# Laravelがインストールできない

Tags: php, laravel, composer

Plesk OnyxでPHPのバージョンを5.3.3から7.1.32に上げて、Laravel5.6をインストールしようとすると（下記コマンド）、

```
$ composer create-project laravel/laravel --prefer-dist manage 5.6

Could not find package laravel/laravel with version 5.6 in a version installable using your PHP version 5.3.3.
```

と言われてインストールできません。

`echo phpinfo();`で見るとPHPのバージョンは「7.1.32」と出るのですが、コマンドラインで`php -v`を打つと「PHP 5.3.3 (cli) (built: Mar 22 2017 12:27:09)」と出ます。これが原因なのでしょうか？

【追記】
PHPのバージョンアップは、Pleskの画面上でPHPバージョンの切り替えにて行いました。

Comment: `which -a php`とコマンドを実行すると、どのパスを示しますか？

Comment: `/usr/bin/php`と出ました。

Comment: PHPは複数バージョンが共存可能なので、どのパスにどのバージョンがインストールされているかを確認する必要があります。[Plesk Onyx PHPバージョンの選択](https://help.gmocloud.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3693/) / `phpinfo`がブラウザから確認しているなら、webサーバの情報も必要となるでしょう。

Comment: ありがとうございます。パスを調べたところ、`/opt/plesk/php/7.1/bin/php`でした。となると、laravelをインストールするcomposerのコマンドはどうなるのでしょうか？基本的なことだと思いますが、すみません…。

Comment: もう一つ `which -a composer` とコマンド実行すると、どのパスを示しますか？

Comment: 遅くなりました。`/usr/bin/composer`と出ます。